# Socket.io flutter error - was not upgraded to websocket

Tags: flutter, socket.io

I/flutter (15398): WebSocketException: Connection to 'https://socket-clock.vercel.app:0/socket.io/?EIO=4&transport=websocket#' was not upgraded to websocket

Comment: how to solve this problem ?